# WinDbg Preview not loading compressed .pd_ symbol files

Tags: debugging, windbg

[WinDbg Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

My symbol path is:

```
     SRV*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

The symbol folder

```
     c:\Symbols\HelloWorld64.pdb\408F6A6B3154428DA5DB17FDD17ABAEE1\
```

has these two files

```
    HelloWorld64.pd_
    refs.ptr
```

To create the above compressed .pd_, I used the [/compress option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/symstore-command-line-options):

```
    SymStore.exe add /compress /f "C:\Development\HelloWorld\Bin\HelloWorld\x64\HelloWorld64.pdb" /s C:\Symbols /t HelloWorld64-Release /v 2.47.0.1 /o

    SYMSTORE MESSAGE: 0 alternate indexers registered
    SYMSTORE MESSAGE: LastId.txt reported id 131
    SYMSTORE MESSAGE: Final id is 0000000131
    SYMSTORE MESSAGE: Copying 
    C:\Development\HelloWorld\Bin\HelloWorld\x64\HelloWorld64.pdb to C:\Symbols\HelloWorld64.pdb\408F6A6B3154428DA5DB17FDD17ABAEE1\HelloWorld64.pd_ [Force: T, Compress: T]

    SYMSTORE: Number of files stored = 1
    SYMSTORE: Number of errors = 0
    SYMSTORE: Number of files ignored = 0
```

However, when loading the DMP file, WinDbg is unable to find **.pd_** but looks for **.pdb** instead:

```
    DBGENG:  C:\Development\HelloWorld\Bin\HelloWorld\x64\HelloWorld64.exe - Mapped image memory
    SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x12
     c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
     HelloWorld64.pdb
     408F6A6B3154428DA5DB17FDD17ABAEE1
     SYMSRV:  UNC: c:\symbols\HelloWorld64.pdb\408F6A6B3154428DA5DB17FDD17ABAEE1\HelloWorld64.pdb - file not found
     SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
     DBGHELP: HelloWorld64.pdb - file not found
     DBGHELP: HelloWorld64 - no symbols loaded
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: how did you endup with .pd_ in first place  it appears you are compiling so  you should have a .pdb not .pd_ did you use pdbcopy / binplace or other utilities to put pdb in symsrv complient path

Comment: To create the compressed .pd_, I used the /compress option from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/symstore-command-line-options


`SymStore.exe add /compress /f "C:\Development\HelloWorld\Bin\HelloWorld\x64\HelloWorld64.pdb" /s C:\Symbols /t HelloWorld64-Release /v 2.47.0.1 /o`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

symsrv can work with uncompressed pdb only if you have compressed pdbs you need a cache where it can be decompressed the walkthrough below done on 
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.19528.1000 AMD64

if you are using symstore to store a compressed pdb then you need a local cache to decompress it before symsrv can locate it

```
0:000> .reload /f
Reloading current modules
.SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x2
         f:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         deto.pdb
         3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272
SYMSRV:  UNC: f:\symbols\deto.pdb\3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272\deto.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: F:\src\deto\deto.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: deto - no symbols loaded
```

symbol not found above as only deto.pd_ exists there stored using symstore.exe

```
F:\src\deto>dir /s /b f:\symbols\deto.pdb\3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272\
f:\symbols\deto.pdb\3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272\deto.pd_
f:\symbols\deto.pdb\3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272\refs.ptr
```

temporarily changed sympath to add a local cache

```
0:000> .sympath srv*f:\test*f:\symbols
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: srv*f:\test*f:\symbols
```

doing a .reload symbols are now accessible in f:\test (it will also copy ntdll.pdb and others from f:\symbols to f:\test before accessing them

compress option is mainly used for symbol server operations (where you have petabytes of symbols for gigabytes of versions) if you compile them simply store then uncompressed and get rid of headaches

```
0:000> .reload /f
Reloading current modules
.SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x8
         f:\test*f:\symbols
         deto.pdb
         3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272
SYMSRV:  UNC: f:\test\deto.pdb\3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272\deto.pdb - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: f:\test\deto.pdb\3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272\deto.pd_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: f:\test\deto.pdb\3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: f:\symbols\deto.pdb\3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272\deto.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  deto.pd_ from f:\symbols: uncompressed
SYMSRV:  PATH: f:\test\deto.pdb\3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272\deto.pdb
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: deto - private symbols & lines 
        f:\test\deto.pdb\3C481DA1FE5E450F947D744F14D014272\deto.pdb
```

Comment: Excellent! Adding the local cache (C:\SymbolsCache) resolved it:
SRV*C:\SymbolsCache*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

As you suggested, I'll remove the compress option locally to avoid this headache.
Fetching remote compressed PDBs are working too and stored in C:\Symbols. 

Thanks!